# Calculating fundamental frequency per sound in R

Tags: r, audio

I am trying to extract the fundamental frequency of a sound in a given window in R. However, so far what I found only gives me the fundamental frequency of a particular point in the audio file, and not the fundamental frequency for the overall period of time.

I have tried using the function `fund` in the package `seewave` as follows:

```
data(sheep)
fund(sheep, from = 0.5, to = 2, type = 'p')
```

and this gives me the plot:

[image]

However, what I want is not the fundamental frequency at each point but the fundamental frequency for the overall sound i.e., in this case, I want one value - about 0.15 kHz - as the fundamental frequency of the sound from 0.5 to 2 secs.

Is there a way to do this? Or do I need to calculate it on my own (taking weighted average?), or is there another package that allows me to do this?

Thank you so much in advance.

Comment: As fund calls ceps, if you call fund without, from=, to=, ceps returns a cepstrum of the the whole segment ?ceps , that you might have to clip out to match your 0.5 to 2. Might be worth a try. With plot = FALSE, you're returned a matrix of values, whose second column is freq in khz. If you need to create such a segment, you'd look at `soundgen`.

Comment: Would it be correct to say that `fund` cannot compute the pitch per sound then (as in, from 0.5-2s the frequency is pretty constant, so might as well get one value to represent the entire sound)? Without from= and to=, I only get a matrix of fundamental frequencies for every unit of time, as you mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

Explore "seewave" package it has various options. Here are few lines(from package) which will give the amplitude and frequency plot for the sound.Hope this would help

```
oscillo(sheep,f=2000)
spec(sheep,f=2000,col="green",plot=2)
```

Link : https://rdrr.io/cran/seewave/man/spec.html

Answer (score 0):

You could change the window length parameter in the call to `fund`. Setting to a power of 2 seems to work best. Choose a window length that is greater than half the number of samples but less than the total number. Here's some code.

```
library(tuneR)
library(seewave)

data("sheep")
sound_of_interest <- extractWave(sheep, from=0.5, to=2, xunit='time')
# find the first power of 2 that is greater than half the length of the samples
first_power_of_2 <- as.integer(log2(length(sound_of_interest)/2))+1
# set a window length to be 2 to this power of 2
wl <- 2 ^ first_power_of_2

fund(sound_of_interest, wl=wl)
#     x         y
#[1,] 0 0.1538462
```